# Ktor server ready but not logging so

Tags: maven, ktor, koin

When I start my Ktor+Koin application the server comes up and returns expected responses on my defined routes. However the doc says that one should wait until the following log entry appears as this proves that the server is ready:

`[main] INFO  Application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080`

But it never comes.

I changed the build tool from `gradle` to `maven` and so had to change the Ktor gradle plugin to maven-assembly-plugin to create the fat jar. I use ktor:2.3.7 and koin:3.5.0. The logger logs on `debug`, I have no errors in the log.

Perhaps I should not worry too much as everything works as expected. What do you think?

Comment: Can you please share the logs you observe?

Comment: Interestingly enough the log was more verbose (and as expected) after I added this dependency to the pom: org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36

Comment: Inserting org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9 also helps. The issue might be explained here: https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder